# Implement interceptors using npgsql and EF Core 6

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm in the process of developing a new application where I'll be utilizing a token or password for authentication with PostgreSQL through EF Core. To facilitate this, I've implemented an interceptor responsible for managing reconnections. However, I've encountered an issue where the interceptor isn't being invoked.

How it is being initialized:

```
services.AddDbContext<BooksContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString))
        .AddInterceptor(new EFInterceptor())
```

This is the interceptor:

```
public class EFInterceptor : IDbConnectionInterceptor
{
    public InterceptionResult ConnectionOpening(DbConnection connection, ConnectionEventData eventData, InterceptionResult result)
    {
        // This code is not getting called when connecting
    }

    //... all other methods here
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!